# Could not find JRE(flex)

Tags: java, apache-flex, actionscript

I've installed java JDK, when I open the console(Windows 7) and write javac.exe or java.exe, its all ok, but when i write mxmlc.exe, it gives me an error that there is not Java runtime environment, how to fix this?

Comment: Which version? The Flex SDK will only work with JRE6

Comment: wow thanks, thats the answer))

Comment: i've installed 1.6 java, but i still get the same error, java -version 1.6, javac.exe works

Comment: By the way: Apache Flex 4.9.0 does support Java 7

Answer (score 1):

propably because the javac.exe and java.exe are part of the jre inside the jdk. the jre's /bin is on your path, the jdk's /bin is not.

EDIT: also you need to let JAVA_HOME point to the right directory

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to install the 32-bit version of the JRE. It seems that is what Flex SDK 4.6 expects.